# How to prevent .htaccess directives from loading

Tags: .htaccess

I have a series of mod_rewrite directives stored in a .htaccess file. They have all been tested and work perfectly.

I want to insert a new directive at the top of the stack that essentially performs as follows:

- if the URL is equal to a certain address, do not execute any other directives

Is this possible to do?

**Amended**

- I want to catch http://mydomain.com/mydir/mysubdir/index.html
- If the URL does not exactly match the address I list in the bullet above then I want the .htaccess directives to handle the request

Comment: Note: it is not the [L] that I am looking for...I am familiar with that. What I do not know what to do is catch the specific URL. thanks.

Comment: this? `Redirect 301 /page1.html http://www.blabla.com/page2.html [R=301,L]`



http://ndesign-studio.com/blog/301-htaccess-redirect

Comment: Well, it is not really a redirect solution that I am after @InTry

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(mydir|mydir1)($|/) - [L]` mydir and mydir1 are now excluded

Comment: That worked @InTry. If you move it to an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks !

Comment: just as note, it has to be at the top of rewrite rules

Comment: Oh yeah...I knew that and that is where I placed it. Thanks for checking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `[L]` flag on the end of the rule

Update:

```
RewriteRule ^(mydir|mydir1)($|/) - [L]
```

mydir and mydir1 are now excluded

Comment: see the comment I added to my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this here:

```
RewriteRule ^myrule$ - [L]
```

This is a kind of do nothing rule which has the marker that this is the [`[L]` last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) rule which should be executed.

Comment: Something like this @rekire ? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/mydir/mysub-dir/ [L]`

Comment: This would the client redirect to that url and won't execute any else rules.

Comment: So is my directive correct or incorrect @rekire? for example...if the URL is http://mydomain.com/some-dir/index.html -- I want the .htaccess directives to handle it. Only when the URL equals http://mydomain.com/mydir/mysub-dir/ is when I want to bypass all other mod_rewrite directives.Thanks.

Comment: If you want a redirect yes, If not try this here: `RewriteRule ^/?mydir/mysub-dir/$ - [L]`

Comment: Well, not really. I tried your `RewriteRule ^/?mydir/mysub-dir/$ - [L]` and it did not work. The .htaccess directives came into play and took over.

Comment: Do you have a query string into the url or does the domain matter?

Comment: No query string -- given the .htaccess directives successfully cover all scenarios from my earlier testing when I built them, all I need to do here is catch a very specific address -- domain name does not really matter, nor does query string. It is almost like a "back door" address that I want to be removed from the flow.

Comment: Your edit seems to point to the whole directory so you could obmit the `$` sign.

Comment: Question for you @rekire. Is this even a RewriteRule directive that I need in order to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) or `[L]` flag for your rewrite rule.

Comment: see the comment I added to my question